# How to represent parent/child structures in recycler view?

Tags: mvvm, android-recyclerview, dependencies, android-room

I am struggling with how to present normalised data in a recycler.

I'm trying to represent the structured lessons of a training course in the recycler, using different item types to represent the phases of the course and the lessons within those phases. I have created the data in MySQL, built a simple asp.net web service on AWS to serve up the training courses in JSON format and successfully called the service from my Android studio app, creating objects for the course, its phases and lessons. I can save this object to SQLite via Room. However, I don't know how best to bind data to the recycler. I originally just observed the lessons and passed them to a list Adapter (this worked) but I also want to show the phases. I've looked for examples on the site but can't seem to find anything other than expandable lists and recyclers within recyclers. Since I know that a recyclers can hold different types of items I suspect there must be something simple I'm missing.

**Fragment**

```java
public class LessonsFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView lstLessons;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private ListItemAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        lstLessons = getView().findViewById(R.id.lstLessons);

    }

Public void onActivityCreated(@NullableBundlesavedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    lstLessons.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new ListItemAdapter();

    viewModel=ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);

    viewModel.getCourse().observe(this,newObserver<Course>(){
    @Override
    Public void onChanged(Course course){
    }
    });
    viewModel.getListItems().observe(this,newObserver<List<ListItem>>(){
    @Override
    publicvoidonChanged(List<ListItem>listItems){
        mAdapter.setListItems(listItems);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    });
}
}
```

**MainViewModel**

```java
Public LiveData<Course> getCourse(){
    return courseRepository.GetCourse()
}
Public LiveData<List<ListItem>> getListItems(){
    listItems=courseRepository.getListItems();
    Return listItems;
}
```

**CourseRepository**

```java
Public LiveData<Course> GetCourse(){
    If (//not up to date){
        //Make retrofit call
        Course newCourse = response.body;
        new DeleteCourseAysyncTask(courseDao, phaseDao, lessonDao).execute();
        new InsertCourseAysyncTask(courseDao, phaseDao, lessonDao).execute(newCourse);
    }
    return courseDao.get();
    }
}
public LiveData<List<ListItem>> getListItems(){
    return listItems;
}

//Async tasks for delete and insert + ...

//This is the code that can't work since it:
// 1) gets null results for phases and lesson
// 2) doesn't update the LiveData 
private static class GetListItemAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        private TrainingCourseDao trainingCourseDao;
        private PhaseDao phaseDao;
        private LessonDao lessonDao;

        private GetListItemAsyncTask(TrainingCourseDao trainingCourseDao, PhaseDao phaseDao, LessonDao lessonDao){
            this.trainingCourseDao = trainingCourseDao;
            this.phaseDao= phaseDao;
            this.lessonDao = lessonDao;
        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            listItems.clear();

            if (phaseDao.getAll().getValue() != null) {
                for (Phase phase : phaseDao.getAll().getValue()) {
                    listItems.add(new ListItem(ListItem.eItemType.PHASE, phase, phase.getName()));

                    if (lessonDao.getAll().getValue() != null) {
                        for (Lesson lesson : lessonDao.getAll().getValue()) {
                            listItems.add(new ListItem(ListItem.eItemType.LESSON, lesson, lesson.getName()));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            this.listItems = (LiveData<List<ListItem>>) listItems;

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Course Dao**

```java
@Dao
Public interface CourseDao {
    @Insert
    Void insert(Course course);

    @Delete
    Void delete(Course course);
//There's actually a "delete all" too but I'll spare you the query
}
```

**Phase Dao**

```java
@Dao
Public interface PhaseDao {
    @Insert
    Void insert(Phase… phase);

    @Delete
    Void delete(Phase phase);
}
```

**Lesson Dao**

```java
@Dao
Public interface LessonDao {
    @Insert
    Void insert(Lesson… lesson);

    @Delete
    Void delete(Lesson lesson);
}
```

**Database**

```java
@Database (entities = {Course.class, Phase.class, Lesson.class}, version=1, exportSchema=false)
public abstract class CourseDatabase extends RoomDatabase{
    private static CourseDatabase instance;
    public abstract CourseDao courseDao();
    public abstract PhaseDao phaseDao();
    public abstract LessonDao lessonDao();


public static synchronized CourseDatabase getInstance(Contextcontext){
    if(instance==null){
        instance=Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
        CourseDatabase.class, "course_database")
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
        .addCallback(roomCallback)
        .build();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

**Course Entity**

```java
private String name;
private String description;
@ignore
private List<Phase> phases;

//public constructor, getters and setters
```

**Phase Entity**

```java
private int courseId;
private String name;
private int sequence;
@ignore
Private List<Lesson> lessons;

//public constructor, getters and setters
```

**Lesson Entity**

```java
private int phaseId
private String name;
private String activities;
private int sequence;

//public constructor, getters and setters
```

**List Item**

```java
public enum eItemType{
        PHASE, LESSON //+there will be others
    }
    private eItemType mItemType;
    private Object mObject;
//public constructor, getters and setters
```

I tried creating a generic ListItem class which can hold a pointer to my phase OR lesson object then making List and building the list when I retrieve the course but I run into problems when I try to access this list in the ViewModel; I get a fatal exception as this approach results in calls to the database on the main UI thread.

All guidance much appreciated. Please don't be TOO harsh on my java-newbie code! and let me know if I need to expand it anywhere :)

Comment: Your plan looks okay, but people won't be able to tell what exactly is causing problem until they see how `courseRepository.getListItems()` is implemented. Another concern is that you are calling `DeleteCourseAysyncTask` and `InsertCourseAysyncTask` at the same time. Better to combine these two operations to eliminate and chance of race condition.

Comment: Thanks for your comment SL. I'd hoped to spare my own blushes and not post my dodgy attempt to get the list items - but you're perfectly right to say it doesn't illustrate what I tried. Thanks too for the comment regarding the race condition. I'm quite new to writing asynchronous code and forgot that these operations don't necessarily happen in the sequence that I want. This is perhaps at the heart of what I'm unable to do: I didn't want to persist the list items because I only really need them for the view whereas I have other things that I may want from Phase and Lesson objects.

Comment: To answer your updated code: (1) You will always get null results for `phaseDao.getAll().getValue()` and `lessonDao.getAll().getValue()` because `getValue()` function does not wait for `LiveData` to emit an item. Instead of `getValue()`, you must observe `LiveData` emission. This also means that using `AsyncTask` is not needed because `LiveData` is already handling this asynchronous access to DB.

Comment: (2) `this.listItems = (LiveData<List<ListItem>>) listItems;` is not the correct way to create a `LiveData`. It is impossible to *convert* a `List` to `LiveData<List>` because they are two conceptually different things.

Comment: One more thing that confuses me is that you are calling `lessonDao.getAll()` for each `phase`. I thought each `phase` supposed to have its own `lesson`, so I need help understanding the reason you are getting the entire list of `lesson` items.

Comment: Thanks again SL; your comments were helpful and I figured out a way to do it in the end. When I get a moment I'll post some code. Essentially my generic ListItem class did the trick. It includes an "Object" property that I can set to Course, Phase, Lesson or whatever. Absolutely I was trying to do something very wrong with LiveData - mostly due to misunderstanding how the asynch code actually works - and I've also combined the delete and re-insert as you suggested. I appreciate your assistance.